# How can I generate a map key to emulator on MAC Terminal

Tags: android, macos, dictionary, android-emulator, terminal

I have a project that uses google maps so I have maps screen but When I was trying to show map,It gives an error and I think that it is related to with this:

```
Running Google Maps API v2 Sample in Emulator
```

but I couldn't find article for mac which terminal command is compatible for it?

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: when I was clicking  Wi-Fi(Setting->Network) on my emulator it gives error

Comment: Yeah, but what is the message?